# AngularJS "not well-formed", but still showing in firefox

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've just started getting into using AngularJS to dynamically display json data on webpages. I have used the ng-repeat with an external json file just fine before, but when I add data before the array, it no longer works in IE and chrome, but shows in firefox with a firebug error. I believe my syntax is right, but obviously something is wrong, and I can't figure it out.

Here is my exact code:

HTML

```
<html ng-app>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dumctrl.js"></script>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Dummy Page</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <table border="1px">
      <tr>
        <th>{{log.name}}</th>
        <th>{{log.xname}}</th>
        <th>{{log.yname}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="entry in log.entries">
        <td>{{entry.id}}</td>
        <td>{{entry.x}}</td>
        <td>{{entry.y}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

dumctrl.js

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('dummy.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.log = data;
  });
}
```

dummy.json

```
{
  "name":"dummy",
  "xname":"xdummy",
  "yname":"ydummy",
  "entries":[
    {
      "id":0,
      "x":0,
      "y":0
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "x":1,
      "y":0
    }
  ]
}
```

The json is validated, and it shows the expected output in ff, I just don't know what's wrong.

Comment: what is the syntax error you get from firebug

Comment: could be same source origin security issue - which would explain different behaviour from different browsers.

Comment: Brad: Just about to add that, firebug says not well formed on dummy.json line 1 char 1

Billy Moon: I'm not sure that's the issue, since I pretty much have a duplicate of this, with only a data array in the json, that has worked every time without fail. The only difference is the addition of the name fields before the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in the space between `[{` and `}]`

I just created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F78T3/2/) and it worked fine:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function myCtrl($scope)
{    
    $scope.log = {
  "name":"dummy",
  "xname":"xdummy",
  "yname":"ydummy",
  "entries":[{
      "id":0,
      "x":0,
      "y":0
    },
    {
      "id":1,
      "x":1,
      "y":0
    }]
};

}
```